# No matching client found for package name 'com.ectare' (My app) - Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-build

I want to use firebase(FCM) to send notifications to my app, but it keeps with that error.
I have a google-services.json with this code:

```
 {
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:200374141305:android:8271646432967402",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.app"
    }
  }
```

And my xml file has this id:

```
    <widget id="com.app" version="3.4.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```

I have already created a new project in firebase to try and register a new one.
I have tried change my app name twice, and nothing change.
Im using phonegap-cli-6.5.0.

Comment: Might be best to post this question to the issue tracker of whatever plugin you're using for push notifications?